# Knowledge required to migrate to Cloud Endpoints API from App Engine Standard

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I 'grew up' on Google App Engine Standard Environment (Python, webapp2, jinja2) and now I would like build an API server to engage with my static frontend client (React, Angular, Vue).

It looks like this is no easy task largely due to the amount of new concepts required to learn — including OpenAPI specs, VM machines, proxies, containerziation, flexible environment and more. Today, the documentation does not provide exploration of the basic concepts involved in building an API. The tutorial is also quite lengthy and I've run into errors while trying it multiple times (at different times of the year).

What are the steps-by-step knowledge that a newbie like me must obtain to make the migration from where I currently stand?

Comment: We can help you if you show the steps you are having problems with, the code/configuration that is a problem, and the errors reported. You are asking for someone to write a tutorial. You already have one.

Answer (score 0):

Currently GCP Endpoints for GAE Standard are in a **pre-release** state.

Having said this, perhaps you just need to **add GCP Endpoints** layer (via Cloud Run and OpenAPI/Swagger) **on top of your existing GAE app** (and/or apps), by following the [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-app-engine-standard) here.